# Can't establish proper routes in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

So sorry to bother y'all, but I was wondering if anyone could help me. I'm having a wee bit of a problem with my code in Laravel, being used to working from scratch rather than with frameworks. I made use of the Laravel Bootstrap Starter Site and I'm trying to add additional pages, but the routing isn't exactly co-operating. It's rather frustrating.

**The Controller: app/controller/community/CommunityController.php**

```
<?php
    class CommunityController extends BaseController {
        public function index() {
            return View::make('community.index');
        }
    }
?>
```

**The View**

```
@extends('site.layouts.default')


{{-- Content --}}
@section('content')
@foreach ($posts as $post)
<div>
    I'm just going to put this here... 

</div>

@endforeach

{{ $posts->links() }}

@stop
```

And finally, last but not least, my routes.

```
Route::get('community', array(
  'uses' => 'CommunityController@index',
  'as' => 'community.index'
));
```

Now, I have this nagging feeling that I'm missing something rather small, but for the life of me I can't figure it out. If anyone would be so kind to explain what I'm doing wrong, I'd appreciate it. Especially since I can prevent this kind of problem happening in the future as well.

With friendly regards,
User who still hasn't picked out a good name

Edit: Sorry I forgot to mention this. I removed public, so I don't know if that influences anything. If it does, again, sorry for forgetting to mention this in the beginning.

Comment: Firstly, I think you should remove the PHP closing tags from your controller file(s) (the `?>`). Secondly, please provide us with the exact error you receive, and the route/full URL you use to get there.

Comment: @MikeAnthony Didn't see your comment, sorry 'bout that. Anyways, I start out at http://localhost:8071/project/ which brings me to the main page. From there, I click on Community, which is coded in the default template.



`<a id="MainMenuRepeater_MainMenuItemHyperLink_0" href="{{{ URL::to('community') }}}">Community</a>`

Then it brings me to http://localhost:8071/betaresponse/community with the error **Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException**.

Comment: Hmmm... what does `betaresponse` have to do with anything? I think you should avoid using `URL::to` here. Just use `href="/community"`. Perhaps something is interfereing with URL generation. Also, check your rendered source when using the `URL::to` method to see if it is hardcoding the `betaresponse` segment. If not, then you have a Javascript module that is interfering.

Comment: Ah, Betaresponse is the project name, so in other words, I'm trying to redirect the link to betaresponse/community. If I simply enter /community it will go to localhost:8071/community rather than /betaresponse/community.

Comment: Indeed - make sure your paths are all setup properly if you're in a sub-directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to bind the whole route to the controller, using

```
Route::controller('community', 'CommunityController');
```

then in your controller you have to prefix the controller methods with HTTP verbs.
Your index() method will be

```
public function getIndex() {
        return View::make('community.index');
    }
```

Comment: I tried these methods, but they end up giving me a **"NotFoundHttpException"**. Basically the link is trying to point me to _http://localhost:8071/project/community_. Should I perhaps use `Route::controller('/community', etc);` ?

Or could the error lie in my default template? I'm linking to the page with `code`<a href="{{{ URL::to('community/') }}}">Community</a>`code`

Comment: Have you configure your project with no public folder ?

Comment: Yes, I removed the public folder, was more much convenient.

Comment: Using the other comments as additional help, I made the necessary changes to the code you provided and it's working like a charm. Thank you so much Salgua, you're a life saver.

Additional thanks to @MikeAnthony, Fractaliste and SyedI.R.

So that other people can read this:
Routes and Controller as indicated by Salgua
Links in Views as indicated by MikeAnthony
And Composer Dump-Autoload as indicated by SyedI.R

Answer (score 0):

Just fire `composer dump-autoload` in root of your project folder from terminal / console.

It'll load your controller which is in subfolder.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. It said it was generating auto-load files, which I assume is the correct thing to occur, however, the link is still non-functional.

Comment: Np. What is the error you get? Screenshot / Text would be helpful!

Comment: I am terribly sorry, not too experienced with tinypic. Hopefully this image is bigger:
http://tinypic.com/r/nwym39/5